# reset variable in for loop of c code

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

I am trying to write some C code to increment a ip address. I want one of the variables "j" to reset back to 0 after it reaches 256 since there are only 255 ip address per octet. My problem is I can't seem to get "j" set back to 0. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

```
int main()
{

    int breakCount = 300;

    int j = 0;
    int x = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < breakCount; i++) 
    {
        printf("class-map type traffic match-all cm%d\n",i);
        printf("match source-address ipv4 100.%d.%d.0\n",x,j);

        j++;

        if (j == 256)
        {
            x++;

            int j = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

/* code snip output */

```
match source-address ipv4 100.0.253.0
class-map type traffic match-all cm254
match source-address ipv4 100.0.254.0

class-map type traffic match-all cm255
match source-address ipv4 100.0.255.0

class-map type traffic match-all cm256
match source-address ipv4 100.1.256.0

class-map type traffic match-all cm257
match source-address ipv4 100.1.257.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried just assigning zero to j ?

```
if (j == 256)
{
    x++;

    j = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `int` from `int j = 0;`  where you reset it (in the loop), as it is now you create a local variable instead of using the one declared before.

Comment: lol... Man I was so close. Thanks guys for the help. I just started trying to learn C. Your suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're incrementing individual octets. It would be much better to convert your dotted IPv4 string to a single 32 bit unsigned int first and then increment.

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote this. Why would you not treat the IPv4 address the same way your computer will? Your network protocols don't care about individual octets. IPv4 addresses are treated as a 32 bit unsigned integer. You should handle them as such. Besides that it would be much easier to increment since you don't have to worry individual octets.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of reseting the variable would be:

```
j = j %256;
if (j == 0) {
   x++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
Some functions like to reset vars printf might be doing it.  You should make an array than print it.
*/
int main() {

```
int breakCount = 300;
int j = 0;
int x = 0;
int list_[breakCount][2];

for(int i = 0; i < breakCount; i++) {

    list_[i][0] = x;
    list_[i][1] = j;

    j++;

    if (j == 256)
    {
        x++;

        int j = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < breakCount; i++) {
    printf("class-map type traffic match-all cm%d\n", i);
    printf("match source-address ipv4 100.%d.%d.0\n", list_[i][0], list_[i][1]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This is similar to the answer marked as accepted. But, this won't work as `int j=0;` creates a new variable `j` inside that if condition and wont' affect the outside one at all.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: You  can try diving it into two loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
```

and

```
for(int i = 256; i < 300; i++)
```

In both cases, initialize j as 0.

Comment: this makes the code less readable as it makes look like you *need* two different loops when the right answer is just to remote the `int` when resetting `j`